# How can I send a list of all Open invoices for a partner in an email template?

Tags: odoo, qweb

How can I send a list of all Open invoices for an partner in a email template?
Is there a way to list all the invoices for a partner in a email template?, I need to sent a single message to every customer what I have, how can I do that?, I just sent a message per invoice...
Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the below way :

**1. Create a email template :**

create the new email template using email.template model and set the invoice method call using object.your_global_method_name() using res.partner model
hear object is the global entity so that you will get the object as res.partner single tone obejct.

**2. Added a new method on res.partner model:**

create a new method which is compute to get the all open invoices and also helpful that method in scheduled action call.

**3. Create a scheduled action :**

Which is helpful for make a automated action for the your remaining open invoice checking.you can set the `Interval Unit` as per your need and make to add the method call which you were created in res.partner model.

**4. Call that method on scheduled action :**
  What ever method which you are created in res.partner that method is called on scheduled action call.

**5. Do not forgot to set the outgoing email configuration and its add the email setting on each partner (customer) :**

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)